# Need to get images and descriptions for various products lined up next to each other and not below each other

Tags: html, css

Here is the existing css:

```
.menuguide_wrap {
width: 700px;
border: 0;
padding-left: 30px;
}

.menuguide_product {
width: 150px;
padding-bottom:15px;
height: 100%;
display: inline;
align: center;
}
```

Here is the html on the page.  I  want to get the two images and text below the images to line up next to each other left to right...and not up and down like it is currently.  Here is the link to the page to see it live..  www.grabyourgreens.com/menu-guide/:

```
<div id="menuguide_wrap" align="center">
<div id="menuguide_product"><a href="image"><img src="image-path" <br /> 
G I -CUCUMBER&nbsp;<br /> 
<span style="color: #99cc00;">ORIGINAL RECIPE</span><br /> 
Slightly caffeinated, sweet.</a></div>
<div id="menuguide_product"><a href="image"><img src="image-path"/><span style="font-        size: large;"><br /> 
G II-SPINACH<br /> 
<span style="color: #99cc00;">ORIGINAL RECIPE</span><br /> 
(50-55% Greens).</span></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to display `#menuguide_product` as `inline-block`.

```css
.menuguide_wrap {
  width: 700px;
  border: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#menuguide_product {
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuguide_wrap" align="center">
  <div id="menuguide_product">
    <a href="image">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
      <br />G I -CUCUMBER&nbsp;
      <br />
      <span style="color: #99cc00;">ORIGINAL RECIPE</span>
      <br />Slightly caffeinated, sweet.</a>
  </div>
  <div id="menuguide_product">
    <a href="image">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" /><span style="font-        size: large;"><br /> 
G II-SPINACH<br /> 
<span style="color: #99cc00;">ORIGINAL RECIPE</span>
      <br />(50-55% Greens).</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```